# Create Javascript rows with user input

Tags: javascript, html-table

How would you start writing a for loop for the code provided below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Rows: <input name="rows" id="rows" type="text"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Make me a table!" onclick="makeTable();"/><br/><br/>

<table border="1" id="theTable">
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
function makeTable(){

//Insert code here AND ONLY HERE!
//Write a for loop to create the number of rows specified in the "row" input field
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whether you've built 'table things' with JavaScript or not, this isn't hard. Where are you stuck? Have you run through the various steps of the problem? Have you constructed any pseudo-code to show what you *should* be doing to answer the problem? Has your tutor, professor or whoever, not given any guidance? Because this *feels* like homework of some kind, so I assume you were taught something in the related classes about how this might be addressed.

Comment: so getting the value inside the two textboxes i can use. 

    var rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
    var cols = document.getElementById("cols").value;

Comment: Yes. Well, that's the first step, I suppose. Keep going. If whatever you're doing doesn't work then please try to debug it, look at the JavaScript console (F12) for any errors, then search the web for solutions to those errors. When you get to something you can't understand, *then* come back and ask a specific question about that problem. But: please take the time to show that you've attempted a solution, and explain how, and where, and why your attempted solution doesn't work.

Comment: Really thank you for your help. I think this is the correct way to make the loop?  for (var r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');}
I am not sure how to apply it though because I dont know how to add the row to the table

Answer (score 0):

As I suspect this is homework I will no provider a full code answer but instead provide you with a few guide lines that hopefully will help you.

You have the html and the javascript, in order to create new html elements you need to use the `document.createElement(type)` function that will create a new element, in your case - td/th ?

Then you need to insert it into your table
You do that by obtaining the table(by id/type) - search the web for this one its very simple.
And then using the append method on is with the created element.

You do all this process with a normal for loop that will run until the `.value` of the input tags you have in your html (Again, search for how to obtain these values)

Good luck =]

Comment: I thank you for not providing the full code, and am following your steps! thank you

Comment: Happy to oblige :), If my answer helped you please consider up-voting or accepting it as an answer to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
function makeTable(){

    // Get values of rows/cols inputs
    var rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
    var cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
    // Check the values are in fact numbers
    if (!isNaN(rows) && !isNaN(cols)) {
        // Get the table element
        var table = document.getElementById('theTable');

        // Iterate through rows
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
            // Create row element
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            // Iterate through columns
            for (var c  = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
                // Create cell element
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                // Setting some text content
                td.textContent = 'R: ' + r + ', C: ' + c;
                // Append cell to row
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            // Append row to table
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be able to reduce to `O(n)` by having two separate `for()` loops. The first one to join all `<td></td>`s together, since we know that the number of columns would be the same. Then, just append the `td` string (which will be the same for all of `r`) to `tr`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>

  Rows: <input name="rows" id="rows" type="text"/><br/>
  Cols: <input name="cols" id="cols" type="text"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Make me a table!" onclick="makeTable();"/>   <br/><br/>

  <table border="1" id="theTable">
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function makeTable(){

   var html = "";
   var row=$('#rows').val();
   var col=$('#cols').val();

   for(var i=0; i<row; i++){
  html+="<tr>";
   for(var j=0;j<col; j++)
   {
       html+= '<td> Your data </td>';
     }
    html+="</tr>"
    }

   $('#theTable').html(html);


    //Insert code here AND ONLY HERE!
    //Write a for loop to create the number of rows specified in the "row" input field
    //create a dom element for the row to be added to the table
  }
   </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

I have kept it simple. Hope it helps.